# Upgrade iOS 12 to iOS 13?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

Seemingly I cannot update using the older IPSW files, only iOS 14.

I have an iPhone 7 test device with iOS 12, and I only want to update to iOS 13 (iOS 13.7).

Every attempt failed with basically the "not authorized" error. Tried with Finder, and iMazing.

How can I update to only iOS 13 (without jailbreaking)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. iOS 14 (specifically iOS 14.1) is the current latest version of iOS available and it supports running on iPhone 7.

Apple has stopped signing iOS 13 and it’s not possible to install it over the air or via IPSW file.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Yet it is hard to imagine that there is no way to setup an iOS 13 test device for development. I'll keep looking...

Comment: @GeriBorbás you’ll need to rely on using an iOS Simulator for that.

Comment: Is there a chance to "jailbreak, update to iOS 13, then un-jailbreak"? And still, end up with iOS 13? I don't want to use jailbroken device for testing (as it may hide permission-related issues that happen on original devices).

Comment: @GeriBorbás No.

Comment: Aw, one more question, if I may. If I use a backup made on iOS 13 to Restore with, will it restore the iOS as well? Or does it restore only content?

Comment: @GeriBorbás Only the content.

Comment: Still can't believe there is no option, iOS 13 is here, vast of our user-base is still using it. Any unofficial/pirate-ee source of signed iOS 13 IPSWs out there? Some iOS images black market?

Comment: @GeriBorbás See this is exactly what Apple doesn't want end-users to do. Meaning, they want the end users to run the latest available version of iOS for supported devices. If you wish to stick with an older version of iOS, the generally recommended approach is to not upgrade.

Comment: I'm using iOS 14.1 personally. But if you make an app for a global user-base, you have to account for n-1 iOS at least. Yet we have iOS 12 users as well. They could leave a door open for developers, this is all I say. Anyway, I opened a DTS with Apple to see if there is any.

Comment: @GeriBorbás That's the reason why Xcode allows you to download simulators for older releases of iOS. If you are a developer and have older iOS releases to support and wish to test on real devices too, a recommended and generally followed practise is to keep relevant iOS devices with older releases installed and not upgrade them.